# Need help finding the Cartesian equation of a line

Tags: vectors

I really don't know how to find the Cartesian equation of $D$ knowing that:

- $B$ belongs to $D$
- $D$ is perpendicular to $D'$
- $A$ and $C$ belongs to $D'$
- $A(1, 3)  , B(4, 0) , C(6, 2)$

Comment: I’m sure that you do. Take it step by step. For instance, the third bullet point says that $D'$ is the line through $A$ and $C$. Can you come up with its equation.

Comment: Yes for that one I already found the  equation of D': x+ 5y = 16.

Comment: Great! Now work backwards up the list from there. $D\perp D'$ and knowing $D'$, what’s a direction vector or normal for $D$? Once you know that, I expect that you know how to produce an equation for $D$.

Comment: D is perdicular to D': from that I can say that  the director vector of D' is a normal vector to D. @amd

Comment: So the normal vector of D is n= [  1 5 ]